# Azure Kinect DK degree of precision for 2D measurements

Tags: azure, precision, kinect, measure

I was wondering what the level of precision is for the Azure Kinect DK if I wanted to mount it and use it to measure 2d shapes (cut pieces of paper) on a table. Has anyone tested this?

Comment: Can you please share more detail on what are you thinking to measure for this shapes and what are you doing with these measurements? What is the scenario you are trying to enable?

Comment: Hi @AIM_david do you have an update?